# mysql select where subquery slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have the following table

```
  id | firstname | lastname | email             |  date
   1  | steven    | smith    | steven@gmail.com     2013-06-10 04:01:25
   2  | Bill      | Johnson  | bill@gmail.com    |  2014-06-10 04:01:25
   3  | steven    | smith    | steven@gmail.com  |  2014-10-10 12:01:25
```

This query returns the emails which have the latest date
so it will return row number 2 and 3. It does not return row number 1 as the date is lower than the date of row number 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  us.email,
  us.* 
FROM
  `users` AS us 
WHERE us.`users` = 
  (SELECT 
    MAX(`date`)
  FROM
    `users` AS u 
  WHERE u.email = us.email)
```

The query works fine for small amount of data, but when I try to run it on 40k rows it takes a very long time. More than 5 minutes

The query is an answer someone posted from my previous question so does the sql fiddle link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338f0/1

Comment: no, thanks it solved it! I added index on date and email

Comment: Take a look at what `EXPLAIN` and/or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` tells you about your query... it won't be good news, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment add an index to the corresponding columns.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try add index on email column (run this code after create table):

```
CREATE INDEX i_users_email
    ON users (email);
```